# How to repeat Tablix header(Grid Header) in Rdl report for every page?

Tags: rdl

How to repeat Tablix header(Grid Header) in Rdl report for every page.
  Saved in PDf format.
  Need In every page of Pdf the header part.
  (If in database contain 100 record then save in PDF format in rdl.
   Then record are coming 2 page i need Table header is coming every page  )
   Please any one help me....

Answer (score 0):

When you design the report, you need to exclude the header from the grouping, and having in the grouping only the rows that are going to contain the data. In that way he header is going to be shown in every page of the PDF